# how to keep a subprocess running and keep supplying output to it in python?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, gdb

I am not able to keep alive a tunnel created by subprocess to fire multiple commands.

first i tried this to execute a subprocess

```
command=['gdb']
process=subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
(out,err)=process.communicate("""file demo
b main
r
""")
print out
```

then i tried this

```
command=['gdb']
process=subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write("b main")
process.stdin.write("r")
print repr(process.stdout.readlines())
process.stdin.write("n")
print repr(process.stdout.readlines())
process.stdin.write("n")
print repr(process.stdout.readlines())
process.stdin.write("n")
print repr(process.stdout.readlines())
process.stdin.close()
```

in first case it executes the commands and then exits the gdb making it impossible to keep suplying commands to gdb and in second case it does not execute after `b main` command (i.e. gdb exits).
so how can i keep on giving more commands to gdb from the program as i require. and how to get output of the gdb after execution of each command.
 command to be given to gdb are not known at the start they can only be entered by user of the python program so passing long strings in 
`process.communicate`
will not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noticed, `communicate()` and `readlines()` are not fit for the task because they don't return before gdb's output has ended, i. e. gdb exited. We want to read gdb's output until it waits for input; one way to do this is to read until gdb's prompt appears - see below function `get_output()`:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from os         import read
command = ['gdb', 'demo']
process = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

def get_output():
    output = ""
    while not output.endswith("\n(gdb) "):  # read output till prompt
        buffer = read(process.stdout.fileno(), 4096)
        if (not buffer): break              # or till EOF (gdb exited)
        output += buffer
    return output

print get_output()
process.stdin.write("b main\n")             # don't forget the "\n"!
print get_output()
process.stdin.write("r\n")                  # don't forget the "\n"!
print get_output()
process.stdin.write("n\n")                  # don't forget the "\n"!
print get_output()
process.stdin.write("n\n")                  # don't forget the "\n"!
print get_output()
process.stdin.write("n\n")                  # don't forget the "\n"!
print get_output()
process.stdin.close()
print get_output()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something along the lines of

```
with Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE) as proc:
    for line in proc.stdout:
        proc.stdin.write("b main")
```

This will allow you to write lines to the process, while reading lines from the process.

Comment: it gives attributeError `with Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE) as proc:
AttributeError: __exit__`

Comment: and i don't want to execute multiple commands on the go. it is important to execute one command and get its output and then execute next command which will be given by user and get its output and so on. just executing 10-20 different commands on the go is not required but i want to keep the subprocess alive, and then add text commands to that, how can i do that?

Comment: The with statement should keep the process alive while you are reading and writing from it. The problem is that you are trying to get all of the output without a method of communicating when it is done giving output (no return value)